# Hadoop: how to deal with No Passwordless policy

Tags: hadoop, ssh, passwords

in hadoop cluster passwordless ssh is a common approach advised by many people, I personally think it is convenient in terms of enable the ssh inside the cluster.

However, what about security? what about in some scenario that password is a mandate? What's the best practice to config ssh in the precondition of a non-blank password?

Thank you. Any discussion is welcome.

Comment: Configuring Hadoop Security - http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_3.html

Kerberos - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742516.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your suggested reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password-less doesn't mean there is no password here, blank password is also considered a password and will be encrypted into a key-pair. By deploying the blank password to slave nodes in the cluster, it enables the SSH without inputting password so all the communication during MapReduce can be conducted efficiently, theoretically providing non-blank password but who would bother to do so? Password-less is the standard practice.